# Return Glue Job Status in Airflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow

I am using an older version of Airflow (1.10). We are using Python operators to trigger Glue jobs because Glue operators aren't available in this version. We have multiple jobs that need to run in a particular order. When we run the DAG, our first job triggers and then it passes as succeeded since the job was successfully started.

We are trying to use boto3 to check the status of the job, but we need it to do so continually. Any thoughts on how to check the status continually then only move on to the next Python operator based upon success?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try to replicate the [`.job_completion` method](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/glue.py#L234) from the [GlueJobSensor](https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/amazon/modules/gluejobsensor). So basically:

```
def my_glue_job_that_waits():

    # botocore call that starts the job

    while True:
        try:
            # botocore call to retrieve job state
            if job_state == "SUCCEEDED":
                # log statement
                return #what you want the operator to return
            else:
                # log statement
                time.sleep(POKE_INTERVAL)
        except:
            # what you want to happen if the call above fails
```

But I highly encourage you to upgrade to Airflow 2 if you can. Long term it will save you a lot of time both being able to use new features and not running into conflicts with provider packages.